# Time derivative of a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My lecturer states that for $\boldsymbol u=\boldsymbol u(\boldsymbol x, t)$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac12\left\vert\boldsymbol{u}\right\vert^2\right) = \boldsymbol u\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol u}{\partial t}$$

How is this so?

---

I know the identity $\left\vert\boldsymbol{u}\right\vert^2=\boldsymbol u\cdot\boldsymbol u$ then can we just apply the product rule to this? i.e.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac12\left\vert\boldsymbol{u}\right\vert^2\right) = \frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\boldsymbol u\cdot\boldsymbol u)  = \frac12\left[\boldsymbol u\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol u}{\partial t}+\boldsymbol u\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol u}{\partial t}\right] = \boldsymbol u\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol u}{\partial t}$$

Can somebody justify that this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If ${\bf u}({\bf x},t) = (u^1({\bf x},t),\cdots, u^n({\bf x},t))$, we have:$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{1}{2}\|{\bf u}({\bf x},t)\|^2\right) &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sum_{k=1}^n u^k({\bf x},t)^2 \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u^k({\bf x},t)^2 \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n 2 u^k({\bf x},t) \frac{\partial u^k}{\partial t}({\bf x},t) \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n u^k({\bf x},t)\frac{\partial u^k}{\partial t}({\bf x},t) \\  &= {\bf u}({\bf x},t)\cdot \frac{\partial {\bf u}}{\partial t}({\bf x},t).\end{align}$$